# This program has a runaway error about iterator

Tags: c++, forward-list

There is a problem with this code. I corrected `preb++` to `++preb` and it was fine, but I don't know why `preb++` can't continue to run. Logically speaking, `preb` and `item` point to the same element. But the next cycle will correct it, making `preb` the element pointed to by `item`. It should continue to operate as usual. Only the newly added elements will be deleted.

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
using std::forward_list;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
int main ()
{
    string s1 {"abc"};
    string s2 ={"abc_list"},temp_str; 
    forward_list<string> flis;
    auto preb = flis.before_begin();
    while (cin >> temp_str)
    {
        preb = flis.insert_after(preb,temp_str);
    }
    for (auto &i : flis)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    preb = flis.before_begin();
    auto it =flis.begin();
    int flag=0;
    while (it != flis.end())
    {
        if ( *it == s1)//compare element
        {
            flis.insert_after(preb,s2);
            it=flis.erase_after(preb++);//the ok code should be it=flis.erase_after(++preb)
            flag=1;
            //cout << "22222222"<< endl;//debug
        }
        else
        {

            preb = it ;
            ++it;
        }
    }
    //cout << "1111111111" <<endl; //debug
    if (!flag)
    {
        flis.insert_after(preb,s2);
    }
    for (auto &i : flis)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it not running properly?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this combination of `insert_after` and `erase_after`? Replace an element?

Comment: *"Logically speaking, `preb` and `item` point to the same element."* -- Since there is no `item` in your code, I'm going to disagree with this assessment. (There is an `it`, presumably short for "iterator", but no `item`.)

Answer (score 0):

In `it=flis.erase_after(preb++);`

- `preb` is incremented and becomes the iterator to the erased node
- you erase the node, which also invalidates `preb`

In `it=flis.erase_after(++preb);`

- `preb` is incremented and becomes the iterator to before the erased node
- you erase the node after the new `preb`, and `preb` remains valid

Note the following on iterator invalidation:

> None of the overloads of `insert_after` shall affect the validity of iterators and references, and **`erase_after` shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements**.

- [[forward.list.modifiers] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/forward.list.modifiers#1)

Always keep iterator invalidation in mind. You could implement the first version in two steps:

```cpp
it=flis.erase_after(preb);
++preb;
```

This would work because `preb` would only be incremented after the erasure takes place, so it wouldn't get invalidated by it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I get it!

Comment: @harn if you found the answer helpful, you can mark it as accepted by pressing the checkmark button on the left :)